# Dropzone.js - prevent empty files from uploading to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I know Dropzone supports the possibility to limit the file size to a certain number of MB (through `maxFilesize`) but is there a way to add a `minFilesize` ? This is because I don't want empty files to reach the server.

I see this is the point in the plugin which determines what to do with the file in case of a too big file size:

```
Dropzone.prototype.accept = function (file, done) {
            if (file.size > this.options.maxFilesize * 1024 * 1024) {
                return done(this.options.dictFileTooBig.replace("{{filesize}}", Math.round(file.size / 1024 / 10.24) / 100).replace("{{maxFilesize}}", this.options.maxFilesize));
            } else if (!Dropzone.isValidFile(file, this.options.acceptedFiles)) {
                return done(this.options.dictInvalidFileType);
            } else if ((this.options.maxFiles != null) && this.getAcceptedFiles().length >= this.options.maxFiles) {
                done(this.options.dictMaxFilesExceeded.replace("{{maxFiles}}", this.options.maxFiles));
                return this.emit("maxfilesexceeded", file);
            } else {
                return this.options.accept.call(this, file, done);
            }
        };
```

I know I could add an extra `else if` here to treat the `minFilesize` scenario but I'd like to stay out of the plugin's code and only do this 'externally' if possible, through the events emmited by the plugin.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Take a look at the "Bieber" example here: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration  See if using a `file.size` condition instead will do the trick.

Comment: Yep, handling it in that callback seems to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration, something along the lines of this should do it:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.size == 0) {
      done("Empty files will not be uploaded.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code works fine for me. But when the parameter  maxFilesize: 500 is with accept function it gives me unpredictable results, Hence remove maxFileSize parameter if you are using it with accept function.

```
var emojiCustomizationDropzone = new Dropzone("#emojiCustomizationDropBox", {
paramName: "images",
accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.size == 0) {
        done("Sorry, Your file is empty, Nothing to upload");
        return;
    } else if (file.size > MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE) {
        done("Sorry, Your file is too large to upload, Maximum file size is 500KB");
    }else {
        done();
    }
},
url: sampleURL,
uploadMultiple: true,
autoProcessQueue: false,
method: "POST",
enctype: "multipart/form-data",
headers: {
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    authorization: "Bearer " + $.cookie("Access_token")
},
    parallelUploads: 1,
    maxFiles: 1
});
```

This accept function does not prevent adding files to the dropbox for me. I can suggest another solution for this. We can add conditions we like to the onaddedfile method. if the files does not match we can user removeFile method from dropzone to remove it form respective dropzone.

```
emojiCustomizationDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
if (file.size == 0) {
    emojiCustomizationDropzone.removeFile(file);
    return;
}
if (file.size > MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE) {
    emojiCustomizationDropzone.removeFile(file);
    return;
}
}
```

Hope this helps someone.